# How does Django implement `filter`? Is it selecting everything then filtering?

Tags: django

I want to return where `x = y` with `Something.objects.get(x=y)`.

I've read there might be a `filter` thing in Django, but I'm wary of whether Django is doing something stupid under the hood like selecting everything from the database in memory and then picking off thing that don't match with python (like the way rails does it).

Is this what Django is doing? If so I'll just run raw SQL.

The only thing I see in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) about `multiple` is `MultipleObjectsReturned` being an exception.

Comment: Downvoat and no answer about the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.filter`. It will return an instance of `QuerySet`. The query is not executed until you try to iterate over the `QuerySet`. This allows you to chain calls to build complex queries.

The query is done in SQL, not in python.

You can inspect the query which will be run by looking at `.query` on the resulting `QuerySet`.

```py
>>> Something.objects.filter(x='y').query
SELECT id, x, etc from something where x='y';
```

`.get` is for fetching a single object.

Answer (score 1):

> (...) but I'm weary of weather Django is doing something stupid under the hood like selecting everything from the database in memory and then picking off thing that don't match with python (like the way rails does it).

**No**, Django's ORM will **create an SQL query**. Unless you in someway patch the object manager, it will thus generate a query where the filtering happens at the *database* side.

If you want *all* elements that satisfy a given condition, you should use `.filter(..)` so:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(x=y)
```

this will return a `QuerySet`: a *collection* (possibly empty) of `SomeModel` objects.

If you want to retrieve a single element, you use `.get(..)`:

```
SomeModel.objects.get(x=y)
```

This will return a `SomeModel.DoesNotExist` if no such record exists, and `SomeModel.MultipleObjectsReturned` if it found two or more records for the given condition.